# How to preview selected image in input type="file" in popup using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

In my code, I am allowing the user to upload an image. Now I want to show this selected image as a preview in this same popup. How can I do it using jQuery?

The following is the input type I am using in my popup window.

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadNewImage">
```

Comment: what server side code are you using to upload it? you will need to use that.

Comment: looks at html5 FileReader

Comment: @Prasad, you have to use some kind of plugin may be, visit this http://plugins.jquery.com/

Comment: you can do this with javascript....look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Answer (score 240, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/)**

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
   <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)**

Comment: Thanks prabu, but its not giving full path of image, its just returning a image name

Comment: which browser you using

Comment: all chrome, mozilla, opera, safari except IE

Comment: use $('#imgInp').val() to get full path

Comment: Amazing trick prabu!,:) is FileReader() is HTML5 API? can you plz provide me links where I can get new html5 API list and their details

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Comment: This is pretty amazing. Got it working in ie10. Definitely doesnt work in ie9 or earlier(by my testing.) Thank you.

Comment: Not supported in IE9 or IE8, but other than that it has pretty good support... http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Comment: How can i do when i have four file input..? please solution how to do..Thank..

Comment: I needed to access the file with "input[0].files[0]", note that I'm also accessing the first position of the input element, otherwise it wasnt working for me

Answer (score 56):

If your are using HTML5 then try following code snippet

```
<img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };

</script>
```

Comment: What is the difference with the accepted answer? I don't see any HTML5 related difference... (and BTW the onload declaration should come before the .readAsDataURL method call)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: this is a clear answer. Didnt get what the 'input' is that parameter in the  @Prabhakaran Parthipan 's one

Answer (score 23):

You can use `URL.createObjectURL`

```js
    function img_pathUrl(input){
        $('#img_url')[0].src = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    }
```

```css
#img_url {
  background: #ddd;
  width:100px;
  height: 90px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" id="img_url" alt="your image">
<br>
<input type="file" id="img_file" onChange="img_pathUrl(this);">
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check my scripts it's working well:

```js
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
#list img{
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px ;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use ajax upload to preview your selected file..
http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload

Comment: But what if he wants to preview the file before he uploads it?