# Display Image after selecting filename

Tags: javascript, struts

I have a form that allows me to browse and select a file.

```
<s:file label="Upload Image : " name="fname"   onchange="readURL(this)"/>
```

What I want to do is display that image immediately after the image has been selected. And this is before the "submit" button on the form has been pressed so the image almost certainly resides Client side. Can this be done?

it doesnt show me any options for onchange event.
how to call functions from onchange event ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457340/how-to-preview-selected-image-in-input-type-file-in-popup-using-jquery