# How to display the selected image in same HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a input tag of type "File" in my phonegap mobile application. I am selecting only images from that tag. Now my issue was How can we display the selected image in the same HTML, If user select the image the image should display in the HTML. Is it possible?

```
<input type="file" id="fileUploader" />
<img id="preview" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

javascript:

```
function readIMG(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#fileUploader").change(function(){
        readIMG(this);
    });
```

The selected image should display in the "selectedImage" Div. Is it possible? Any suggestions please

Comment: u mean i select image using File control and then it should show me Uploaded file?

Comment: Isn't this question same as [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded).??

Comment: Google is your friend. Google your question before posting it here. @Precious

Comment: @vinod, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18457580/2501044

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this method

add image in seleced div

`<img id="preview" src="#" alt="your image" />`

```
         function readIMG(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#fileUploader").change(function(){
        readIMG(this);
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3275/)

Comment: For this I need to use Jquery.ui.css and jquery.ui.js ?

Comment: @Precious no nedd it is jquery solution

Comment: Need to use Only Jquery.js or Jquery.min.js also needed?

Comment: I am using Jquery but it is not displaying the image. I am using same code which is posted by you

Comment: I am working with mobile application using phonegap in android platform

Comment: @Where you put this code,update the question with relevant code

Comment: It should be in side that.