# Inserting and using the user uploaded image in html and javascript

Tags: html

This is my code and I need to select the file uploaded by the user display it on the screen and then use it in an API

```
<div class="first">
            <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)"</p>
            <p><img id="output" width="200" /></p>
</div>

var loadFile = function(event) {
    var image = document.getElementById('output');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
```

Comment: Please guide me how can I do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preview selected image in input type="file" in popup using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457340/how-to-preview-selected-image-in-input-type-file-in-popup-using-jquery)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/9375533

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually you code is not wrong you just missing ">" before

```
<p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"</p>
```

change it to

```
<p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)"></p>
```

Your final code will look like this good luck.

```html
<div class="first">
  <p><input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"></p>
  <p><img id="output" width="200" /></p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var image = document.getElementById('output');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: no actually that was just a mistake while I was copying the code to post here ... I wanted to know how can I take this image which I am displaying on the screen and use it perform image analysis using Google's Vision Api .

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in the link to upload files on GCloud Bucket using Node.js
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/

PS. You can do it for any language just type gcloud-< language > in your search bar you'll find the steps to do so in your language 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji1DWCTI05A This video by Sandip Dinesh solved my query , hope it solves yours too :)